# Is Paypal Sandbox offline?

Tags: paypal

Sorry for asking here, but this is a bit of an emergency and I know from past experience, it could take more than 7 days to get a response from Paypal.

I am working on a project that, about 10 days ago, was working fine. 2 Days ago I returned to the PP portion and all of a sudden, I am getting no response from Paypal.

This is the URL I am calling:

https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

And absolutely no response is being returned. I'm certain that before it at least returned an error if no parameters are included. But now, nothing at all with or without parameters.

Comment: Nothing would surprise me. They don't seem to take developers at all seriously.

Comment: Trust me, we do. Can you tell me why you feel that way? Anything we can do better? Happy to address any concerns directly. Email is in my profile. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Paypal does have a [status page](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus) for the live site. Not sure if it still extends to the sandbox, tho. There was a major outage on the live end yesterday.

Which API are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am using the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have issues with this? It's working fine for me. I don't believe we had an outage either.

```
$ curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.43.75.39...
* connected
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (23.43.75.39) port 443 (#0)
*a lot of SSL stuff*
> GET /v1/payments/payment HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> Accept: */*
>

* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 7177ce39c4142
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 0
< DC: origin1-api.sandbox.paypal.com
< Date: Sun, 03 Nov 2013 12:07:31 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: DC=origin1-api.sandbox.paypal.com; secure
<
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Note the HTTP 401 response (because I didn't specify a valid Authorization header with an access token for the request).